# match files to dll

Tags: asp.net

say you have a huge compiled asp.net site on a live server and a development server.
you make changes to a few files on dev and compile...now you want to publish those
changes without copying up the whole site...just compiled stuff in /bin that has changed.

anyone know of a good way to automate this?

was thinking would be nice if you could somehow associate the source files you changed
with the files in /bin that are dependent on them, either at compile time or after.

Answer (score 1):

For VS2010 you can use [Web Deployment](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/29/vs-2010-web-deployment.aspx).

Here's the Web Deployment article for [VS2008](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/28/vs-2008-web-deployment-project-support-released.aspx).

And, finally, if you are unfortunate enough to be using VS2005, you can find that information [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/11/06/429723.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a synhronization tool like microsoft sync toy, or use xcopy with /d param  in postbuild options or robocopy.